# Bivariate normal density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$( X, Y)$ have a bivariate normal density centered at the origin with
$E(X^2)$ = $E(Y^2) = 1$, and $E(XY) = p$ . In polar coordinates $(X, Y)$ becomes
$(R,\Phi)$ where $R^2 = X^2 + Y^2$. Prove that $\Phi$ has a density given by

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-p^2}}{2\pi(1-2p\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi))}$$
And is uniformly distributed iff $p = 0$. (To this point everything is clear)

what i do not understand is how to conclude that
$P\{XY > 0\} =  \frac{1}{2} +\pi^{-1} \arcsin (p)$ and $P\{XY < 0\}= \pi^{-1} \arccos (p)$.